# How many integers $a,b,c$, both positive and negative, such that $P=a^b b^c c^a$ is a prime number?

Tags: number-theory

> How many integers $a,b,c$, both positive and negative, such that $P=a^b b^c c^a$ is a prime number ?

If $a,b,c$ are positive, then two of $a,b,c$ equal to $1$. Assume that $b=c=1$, then $a$ is any prime number.

WLOG, if $c<0$ and $a,b>0$, then $a$ must be even, so $a=2$, thus $b=1$ and $c=-1$

If $a,b,c<0$, then $P$ is smaller than $1$, so $P$ won't be a prime.

However if only one of $a,b,c$ is positive, how can we find $a,b,c$ ?

Answer (score 2):

WLOG assume $b,c<0$, $a>0$. Then $a^b$ and $b^c$ will be fractional unless $a=1$, $b=-1$. So we need to find $1\cdot (-1)^c \cdot c=p$ for $c<0$. Since $c$ is negative, it must also be odd so that $(-1)^c$ will be negative and the entire product will be positive. Hence, $c$ can be the negative of any odd prime.

Comment: What if $a^bb^c|c^a$ ?

Comment: @apple If $a^bb^c\mid c^a$ then either $|a|=|b|=|c|=1$, in which case the desired product is not a prime, or $|c|>1$, in which case $b^c= \frac{1}{b^{|c|}}$. Moreover unless $a=1$, $c^a$ (and hence the product) will be composite. So for the product to be a prime $p$, $c=p\cdot b^{|c|}$, which results in a recursively expanding exponential unless $|b|=1$.

Comment: Why should the product be composite just because $c^a$ is composite?

Comment: $a^bb^cc^a=p$. If $p$ is a factor of $a$ or $b$, then it appears as a power in a denominator, so $|c|=np$, with either $a=|b|+1$ or $ a=|c|+1$ so that the entire product contains one net $p$. But $p$ cannot be a factor of both $c$ and $|c|+1(=a)$, so $p\not \mid a$. If $b=-mp$, then $a=|b|+1$. So $(|mp|+1)^{-mp}(-mp)^{-np}(-np)^{|mp|+1}=p$, and this can only be the case with respect to $p$ if $|mp|+1-np=1$, or $m=n$. That leaves other denominator factors unreconciled. Ergo $p\not \mid ab$. $c^a=(-np)^a$ which renders itself and the product composite except when $a=n=1$.